# How to skip reading lines beginning with #?

Tags: java

I want to write a program that reads many values from a .txt file. Lines beginning with # should be skipped.

```
String a,b,c,d,e,f...;  
File file=new File("test.txt");  
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

a=reader.readLine();  
b=reader.readLine();  
c=reader.readLine();  
......  
reader.close();
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have an array than a whole lot of separate `String` variables?  Then  you could do all your reading inside a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **don't store every `String` in lot of variables**, instead use a `Collection`. For this case, a [`List<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) will suffice.

Then, just read the new line from `BufferedReader` and check if it starts with `#` character. If it does, then don't add it to the `List`.

```
List<String> fileData = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.charAt(0) != '#') {
        fileData.add(line);
    }
}
reader.close();
//use the content of fileData to parse your file as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you should be storing the lines in a data structure. So, you would use a loop that iterates through all the lines in the text file and an if statement inside that stores the line only if it doesn't start with `#`

Answer (score 0):

Though ***Luggi Mendoza***'s answer is correct, java 8 allows to do it in more elegant way.

```
List<String> strings = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))
        .filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```